# deploying with Capistrano within one file to different applications wi

Tags: deployment, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a rails application "master" which i deploy with capistrano.
It's deployed from master branch of the repository.
Then a new application was created "demo". it's code is stored in the demo branch of the same repository. I need to write deployment for that app.
 it should do:
`cap master deploy` deployment of master application
`cap demo deploy` deployment of demo app

Currently when i put deployment of master in namespace it gives me an error

```
roles cannot be defined in a namespace (NotImplementedError)
```

and i need roles to restart application

```
desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "[ -f #{unicorn_pid} ] && kill -USR2 `cat #{unicorn_pid}` || #{unicorn_start_cmd}"
  end
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main point is that namespace & module can't be used here. But you always can

```
task  :demo do
# code here
end
```

using **task** won't result in an error